# Two template classes use each other as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

Two template classes can use each other as template argument, but if I use anything defined in one class scope, it cannot be compiled.

```
template<class B> struct A {
    typedef A *pointer;
};
template<class A> struct B {
    //typedef A::pointer APtr;
    //using APtr = A::pointer;
    //APtr pa;
    A::pointer pa;
};

struct AA;
struct BB;
struct AA : public A<BB> {};
struct BB : public B<AA> {};
```

VS2017 complained:

```
1>c:\test.cpp(59): warning C4346: 'pointer': dependent name is not a type
1>c:\test.cpp(59): note: prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
1>c:\test.cpp(60): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'B<A>' being compiled
1>c:\test.cpp(59): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'pointer'
1>c:\test.cpp(59): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\test.cpp(69): warning C4091: '': ignored on left of 'A<BB> *' when no variable is declared
```

Is it also involved [circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205367/two-template-classes-being-composed-of-a-member-of-each-other#16205668)? Is there one possible way to fix it?

Comment: Notice that `template<class B>` is unrelated to `template<class> struct B;` even if you use same name. (it is so just confusing). usual way is to use name `T` (if no relevant/better names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc's error message is much more informative:

```
t.C:8:5: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘A::pointer’ because ‘A’ is a dependent scope
    8 |     A::pointer pa;
      |     ^
      |     typename
```

And doing that, makes gcc happy:

```
template<class B> struct A {
    typedef A *pointer;
};
template<class A> struct B {
    //typedef A::pointer APtr;
    //using APtr = A::pointer;
    //APtr pa;
    typename A::pointer pa;
};

struct AA;
struct BB;
struct AA : public A<BB> {};
struct BB : public B<AA> {};
```

This is not a template circular reference. The only reference in the first template is to its own template parameter. Just because its template parameter happens to be named `B`, and there is another template defined with the same name, later, doesn't make the template parameter a reference to the other template.

And as far as the actual classes go, forward declarations, as in this case, make circular references between classes possible.