# Extend a template classe using the type definition in subclass

Tags: c++, templates

I imitated the `std::enable_shared_from_this` to create a template class, but I made the class use the type definition in its subclass.
Unfortunately!
Although I used `typename`, after compiling,

```cpp
// 
// https://ideone.com/eYCBHW  http://ideone.com/eYCBHW
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

template<class _S> struct A {
};

template<class _Subclass>
class Global {
public:
    typedef typename _Subclass::connection_t connection_t;
    //std::map<std::string, _Subclass::connection_t> connections;
    //std::set<_Subclass::connection_t> connections;
    //using typename _Subclass::connection_t;
    //typename _Subclass::connection_t* connections;
    //connection_t* connections;
};

class CConnection {};

class SConnection;

class Client : public Global<Client> {
public:
    typedef CConnection connection_t;
};

#if 0
class Server : public Global<Server> {
public:
    typedef SConnection connection_t;
};
#endif

class SConnection {};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

GCC complained:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Global<Client>’:
prog.cpp:25:23:   required from here
prog.cpp:14:43: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Client’
  typedef typename _Subclass::connection_t connection_t;
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:25:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class Client’
 class Client : public Global<Client> {
       ^~~~~~
```

How to solve it?

References

- [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)
- [C++ - meaning of a statement combining typedef and typename [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385418/c-meaning-of-a-statement-combining-typedef-and-typename)
- [Two template classes use each other as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537603/two-template-classes-use-each-other-as-template-argument)

Comment: Be aware that identifiers starting with underscore followed by a capital letter (`_S`, `_Subclass`!) as well as those containing two subsequent underscores are reserved for the implementation (i. e. the compiler).

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. A class cannot be defined until its superclasses are defined first. Therefore, you can't reference something that's defined in a subclass from its superclass, using the CRTP design pattern. There is no solution. You must restructure things, somehow.

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you want to achieve, please? It's not clear to me from the code... From what i gather, it's CRTP you want...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you can refrence something that's defined in a subclass from its superclass, that's the whole point of CRTP. But you only can do it inside superclass member functions.

Comment: How about `template<class Subclass, class Connection> class Global`?

Comment: Sam Varshavik is correct. The most straightforward workaround is to use type traits.

Comment: No wonder that when compiling `template<class _S> struct A {};` on my android mobile phone, GCC always complained: expected identifier before numeric constant . It seems that I must restructure and can do only in this way (@n.m) for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a `typedef` at class level requires the template arguments to be complete types. How would the compiler otherwise be able to check, if the type provided as argument actually has some equivalent typedef itself?

Analogously, the following is going to fail:

```
class C;
using G = Global<C>; // C is not a complete type!
class C // too late...
{
    // ...
};
```

Problem with [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), which is what you're trying to implement, that at the point you try to derive, the class is not yet complete, just as in my example above:

```
class Client : public Global<Client> // client is not yet complete!
{
}; // only HERE, it will get complete, but that's too late for above
```

Ever wondered, though, why member variables are known within member functions even though being declared *after* the function? That's because

```
class C
{
    void f() { n = 12; }
    int n = 10;
};
```

is compiled as if it was written as:

```
class C
{
    inline void f();
    int n = 10;
};

void C::f() { n = 12; } // n is known now!
```

This is at the same time the clue *where* you can use the template argument the way you intend:

```
template<class T> // different name used! *)
class Global
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        typedef typename T::connection_t connection_t; // possible here!
        // (similar to why you can use the static cast as in the link provided)
    }
};
```

That won't help, though, with your members:

```
std::map<std::string, typename T::connection_t> connections;
//                     ^ additionally was missing, but won't help either
```

`T` still remains incomplete at this point.

Within the comments, though, you only seem to use the connection type. If you don't need the client or server class for any reason other than the typedef, you can solve the issue pretty simply:

```
template<class T> // different name used! *)
class Global
{
    std::map<std::string, T> connections;
    //                    ^  use T directly
};

class Client : public Global<CConnection>
//                             ^ make sure it is defined BEFORE
{
    // ...
};
```

Otherwise, you need to fall back to other means, e. g. the [pimpl](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/pimpl.html) [pattern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl), where you would let the implementation class inherit from the template.

<sub>*) Identifiers starting with underscore followed by captial letter, as well as those containing two subsequent identifiers, are reserved for the implementation (i. e. for use by the compiler). Defining your own such ones yields undefined behaviour.</sub>

---

**Edit** (stolen from the comments):

If you need client or server from within `Global`, you could provide both as *separate* template paramters as well:

```
template <typename Base, typename Connection>
{
    // use Connection directly, e. g. for member definitions
    // and Base within member functions as mandated by CRTP
};

class Client : public Global<Client, CConnection>
{ /* ... */ };
```

Comment: Good! I have to do just like this, adding a template argument