# Specify template argument by subclassing

Tags: c++, oop, templates

When I inherit from a templated class and provide the argument during the inheritence, how do I have to handle functions from the parent class, which use the template argument?

For example with this class as the parent:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Parent {
public:
    virtual T someFunction(const T& data);
};
```

and I try to inherit like this:

```cpp
class CharVersion : Parent<char> {
public:
    T someFunction(const T& t) override {
        return 'c'
    }
};
```

How can I get the function in the child to act like:

```
char someFunction(const char& t) override {
    return 'c'
}
```

The compiler obviously doesn't know `T` in the subclass, so how can I express this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57546714/56541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `Parent<char>`, the compiler effectively generates a class definition as if you had substituted `char` into the template text. That is, behind the scenes it's as if the parent class of `CharVersion` is the following template instantiation:

```cpp
class Parent_char {
public:
    virtual char someFunction(const char& data);
};
```

You can write your subclass just as if you were extending that class. (Of course, the name of the generated template instantiation is not `Parent_char`, but that's unlikely to matter.)

Comment: Thanks, always appreciate some an explanation over just 'do this'.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CharVersion : Parent<char> {
public:
    T someFunction(const T& t) override {
        return 'c'
    }
};
```

should be

```
class CharVersion : Parent<char> {
public:
    char someFunction(const char& t) override {
        return 'c'
    }
};
```